# Delete rows from two differences tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo

As the title explained it, I want to delete rows from two different tables.

Is this case, I want to remove all user where `UHL_HotelId` is equal to `cus_DVndBgfwSVaZhe`.

___ Users table

```
|--------|
| USR_Id |
|--------|
|    100 |
|    102 |
|    103 |
|    104 |
|    105 |
|    106 |
|    107 |
|--------|
```

___UsersHotelsLink

```
|--------|------------|--------------------|
| UHL_Id | UHL_UserId | UHL_HotelId        |
|--------|------------|--------------------|
|      1 |        100 | cus_DVndBgfwSVaZhe |
|      2 |        101 | cus_DVndBgfwSVaZhe |
|      3 |        102 | cus_DVndBgfwSVaZhe |
|      4 |        103 | cus_DVndBgfwSVaZhe |
|      5 |        104 | cus_DVndBgfwSVaZhe |
|      5 |        105 | cus_DVndBgfwSVaZhe |
|      6 |        106 | cus_GHbnGhGgu3lbnw |
|      7 |        107 | cus_GHbnGhGgu3lbnw |
|--------|------------|--------------------|
```

My try is the following:

```
DELETE a.*, b.* 
FROM ___Users a 
JOIN ___UsersHotelsLink b 
    ON b.UHL_UserId = a.USR_Id 
WHERE a.UHL_HotelId = 'cus_DVndBgfwSVaZhe';
```

Why my query isn't working please ?

Comment: Typo: `a.UHL_HotelId` should be `b.UHL_HotelId`

Comment: Your query works fine with the typo fixed. See http://rextester.com/ZZIR99492

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a foreign key relationship between the two tables you can use

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

which "allows you to delete data from child tables automatically when you delete the data from the parent table"

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: can you give the solution with an example from the question?

Comment: I would expect the foreign key relationship to go the other way.